# Specify the type of parameter for DELETE request in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, parameters, http-delete

I would like to do a `DELETE` request with **unspecified** number of parameters `a=someValue`. There is 2 main ways of supplying parameters to my understanding

1. Query parameters. `?a=someValue` . This approach turn everything into
   string and since I allow any number of parameters, I cannot know
   which one is String, Boolean or Integer
2. Parameters in Body.This approach goes against the spec of `DELETE` operation to **not** have a body. Some server even strip away the body-content. But as I
   send an json object, user can specify which type of value each of
   their parameters has.

What would be your approach for this?

Comment: `DELETE` method may or may not have the body, you can use the body for sending data if required, you may refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE

Answer (score 1):

I'd use query parameters over body as the DELETE method has an optional body. Some clients may choose to ignore the body totally.